# Roguelike game on Heroku server: Libtcod dependence

Tags: python, heroku, libtcod

I am trying to serve up game logic in a Heroku Python app. I'm using the [libtcod library](https://bitbucket.org/libtcod/libtcod) for some basic tasks (mostly Field of View calculations) and I'm having trouble getting it to run there.

Right now it's getting hung up on libSDL not existing. Crash log:

```
app[web.1]: import libtcodpy as libtcod
...
app[web.1]: OSError: libSDL-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The readme says: "To be able to compile libtcod on Linux, make sure that following packages are installed : gcc, g++, make 
, zlib 
, libpng12 
, libsdl1.2 
, upx 
, electric-fence
,libpng12-dev 
, libsdl1.2-dev "

I've tried adding libSDL to my pipfile and requirements.txt but this was not effective.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have libsdl installed on the dyno. Installing additional packages is not supported, but there are some workarounds described here:
https://help.heroku.com/IYRYW6VB/how-do-i-install-additional-software-packages-that-my-application-requires

Comment: I think I got libSDL working, now I'm getting the same thing for libGL but the same workaround is not helping.